# How can I combine multiple coverage-html reports to a single report

Tags: php, laravel, code-coverage, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

My web services are written in Laravel 5.6 and these are utilised by a mobile app written in Cordova. I am using Katalon Studio to carry out testing of this mobile app and services consumed by it and I am able to achieve it. 
Also, I am able to produce a coverage report, every time a request is initiated from mobile app to web services but the problem here is, it is giving me coverage report of a specific portion based on the endpoint hit by mobile app. 
Now, I have several html coverage reports generated for web services and looking for a work around to combine all these reports.

PS: Also, I tried to generate clover XML coverage reports and able to combine them but don't know how to graphically represent it.

Kindly helps me on this, any suggestions would be highly appreciated!